# The compiler creates a constructor of N args when I have N public member variables and no private ones. What is happening here?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, class-constructors

The following code compiles and runs as expected, unless I uncomment one of the two commented out lines that I have labelled with "prevents compilation":

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
    public:
    int count;
    std::string foobar;
    //Animal() = delete; // prevents compilation

    void squeak() const {
        std::cout << count << ". Squeak from " << foobar << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    //int priv; // prevents compilation
};

int main() {  
    std::string foo{"foo"};
    Animal mouse(1, foo);
    //Animal mouse{1, foo};
    //Animal mouse{1, foo, 3};
    mouse.squeak();
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

What is happening regarding constructors here, what is this mechanism called and when should one use it?

Comment: [Direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), using the [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as "aggregate initialization".

When your class is an "aggregate", brace-initialization can be used to populate your members.  When it is not, it cannot.

Aggregates are classes that are just a bundle of members.  Like an aggregate rock, which is made by smooshing together a bunch of different materials.

You are looking at two ways to prevent your class from being an aggregate.  One of them is having a private member, and the other is by you explicitly having a constructor.

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

can be initialized via

```
foo f = {1,2};
```

There are a bunch of relatively complex rules about when aggregate initialization occurs.  But you ran into the two most common ones here.

For the most part, when you disable aggregate initialization on a class by adding code, the effect is a build break not incorrect code.  So it isn't a real huge pain point.

I do strongly advise you to:

```
int count = 0;
std::string foobar;
```

initialize `int`s like that at the point of declaration in a class.  This won't block aggregate initialization, but when going from aggregate initialization to non-aggregate initialization variables can become uninitialized in some situations if you don't do this.